# adapter to use for listview that shows chat messages

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-cursoradapter

Which is the best adapter to use for listview that shows chat messages?

this is because when i use cursoradapter, and a new message is received or sent, i have to change the cursor that my cursoradapter subclass is using. and the result is that the user will see **all the chat messages** been refreshed on the listview and this is not good.

on the other hand, when i use arrayadapter,it takes time for all chat messages **to be loaded from database, stored in an arraylist, then populated in my listview** and this results in my activity **hanging** for some time.

Comment: You can use BaseAdapter for this.

Comment: @SurenderKumar  have you ever used it? is it the best?

Comment: Yeah i use this adapter only. This is main adapter class inside this other adapters come.

Comment: Dood, you must implement a Content Provider

Comment: @SurenderKumar let me try it and i wil tell you the results. i hpe it will also cater well for chats deletion and insertion. do you have a good working example that you can show me?

Comment: @User3 what do you mean men.

Comment: [Read this](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)  and [Read this](https://github.com/spacecowboy/AndroidTutorialContentProvider)

Comment: ListView [example](http://androhub.com/android-listview/) using BaseAdapter and ListView load more items [example](http://androhub.com/load-more-items-on-scroll-android/).

Comment: I think Base Adapter is Good for Chat System and also in your database or activity put pagination system which is good. because load more data when require.

Comment: @DhavalkumarSolanki how do you put pagination system and what is its importance

Comment: create one key which store your page number in your message table like when i got a message and  and total number of message in my table 100 and already stated 10 record per page, after that  divide total number of record by 10 and they getting new page number which store with data , and when you want it by page wise then search with page key and increment or decrements for new page record.